# Cluster geographical locations(long/lat) which are within 30 min of commute to each other?

Tags: python, api, maps, cluster-analysis, duration

I am trying to cluster geographical locations(long / lat) where the distance between data points in a cluster should be less than or equal to 30 min from each other. I can calculate duration between data points using google map api. How can I cluster those sites which are within 30 minutes commute from each other ?
Image attached for reference:

[image: Click here]

Comment: This appears to be an open-ended question on the order of "teach me how to solve this problem".  Such questions are out of scope for Stack Overflow.  [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to above mentioned question is making use of agglomerative hierarchical clustering with parameter complete linkage = True.

Answer (score 1):

You do realize that this is not transitive?

A to B can be 30 minutes, so they should be in the same cluster.

B to C is also 30 minutes, so they should be in the same cluster.

But A to C is 60 Minutes, so they shouldn't.

So your clusters are not well-defined. First you'll need to identify what you really want. Then try researching existing algorithms!

Comment: If A to C is 60 min then it should be shown as an outlier. Cluster should only include those data points which are less than or equal to 30 min commute from every other point in the cluster.

Comment: But they are within 30 minutes from B! Consider London, this situation arises all the time.

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally clear what you're asking here, but from what I understand you're trying to make an association between two points based on longitude and latitude to one another.

So let's say I compare two points, A and B, using the API you mentioned. You could use a dictionary to associate two points with one another. Let's say I have a class something like this:

Point.py

```
class Point(object):
    def __init__(latitudeToSet, longitudeToSet):
        self.latitude = latitudeToSet
        self.longitude = longitudeToSet
        self.pointsInRange = {}
```

Then in the main program file, you could use it (as a basic example) like this:

```
import Point

def main:

    someNewPoint = Point(0, 0)
    someOtherPoint = Point(1, 1)

    if ( googleAPI.isInRange( (someNewPoint.latitude, someNewPoint.longitude), 
        (someOtherPoint.latitude, someOtherPoint.longitude) ) ):

        someNewPoint.pointsInRange["someOtherPoint"] = someOtherPoint
        someOtherPoint.pointsInRange["someNewPoint"] = someNewPoint

    #From here just check if one point exists in another's dictionary.

    if "someOtherPoint" in someNewPoint.pointsInRange:
        #Do stuff because you know the points are in range.
```